# Single configuration setting for multiple WCF services

Tags: .net, wcf, deployment

We have a scenario where we have multiple WCF services hosted on the same server connecting to same database. But currently they all have their separate web.config files. So each time there is some change or new deployment to another server, each and every web.config needs to be changed.

Is there a way we can have a single configuration (be it on a file or in memory/db) which can be shared among all the services on any given server? If so what would that be? If not, why not? If we shouldnt shouldn't go for this approach, why not?

Currently we have such a hierarchy (Folder structure)

```
Services

 - Service1 
 - Service2
 - ...
 - ServiceN
```

Note: I asked the same on "Programmers" but no one responded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is possible after all. What I did is following, I converted the services' containing folder as application in IIS and put the common web.config within that folder. This required to delete the individual web.config files of each web service.

```
Services (Convert as application)

 - Service1 
 - Service2
 - ...
 - ServiceN
 - web.config
```

Now if you need certain service to user a different config file or use different values, simply put the web.config within that service and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for the `machine.config` file. Think of it as web.config's bigger sibling. You can put common configuration items in the machine.config that will propagate to all of the child web.configs for an instance of IIS. If you have any conflicts, you will either have to remove them in code for the web service or modify the web.config to remove the value before adding it back locally.

[Here's a link to the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229697%28v=vs.90%29.aspx).